# Removing duplicate data from a column

Tags: oracle, duplicates

I have a table with following structure

```
    Id  Pro_id      name        price
    ----------------------------------------
    1   001          ABC        200
    1   002          XYZ        100
    1   003          XYZ        150
    2   004          PQR        100
    2   005          PQR        100
    2   006          LMN        200
    2   007          LMN        300
    2   008          DEF        150
```

As you can see there are some duplicate names in 'name' column.
I want to remove all the duplicate names(just need to keep first entered name and remove remaining)

So my table should look like-

```
Id  Pro_id      name        price
----------------------------------------
1   001         ABC          200
1   002         XYZ          100
2   004         PQR          100
2   006         LMN          200
2   008         DEF          150
```

I tried following to get duplicate names-

```
SELECT ID, NAME, count(NAME) FROM TABLENAME
GROUP BY ID, NAME HAVING count(NAME)>1
```

But now I am unable to go further, stucked in how to delete the records.

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "first" in SQL as the order of select is generally undefined, so the following will keep entries with the minimum value of `Pro_id` for duplicated names, but you are free to define a different aggregator:

```
DELETE FROM tablename 
WHERE Pro_id NOT IN (SELECT MIN(Pro_id) FROM tablename GROUP BY name);
```

Comment: seems easy let me try this

Answer (score 2):

You may try below SQL (In MySQL it works)

```
delete t1.* from tablename t1
    inner join
tablename t2 ON t1.name = t2.name
    AND t1.Pro_id > t2.Pro_id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 DELETE FROM table_name
 WHERE rowid NOT IN
               ( 
                 SELECT MIN(rowid)
                 FROM table_name
                 GROUP BY column1, column2, column3...
               ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
delete from table1 
where rowid in 
( 
    select rid
    from  
        (
        select  rowid as rid, 
                row_number() over (partition by name order by pro_id) as rn
        from    table1
        )
    where rn > 1
)
```

*Havent tested it*